# How to install protocol buffers with Objective C/iOS 5 SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, protocol-buffers

Does anyone know how to get protocol buffers working with the most recent version of the iOS SDK?

I tried the instructions given here: http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers

I have successfully installed 'protoc' and have also successfully compiled Objective-C output files using it, but the project that it tells you to list as a dependency is outdated and I get errors when I try to build my app.

Alternatively then, does anyone know to make the project compatible with the most recent version of the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the related IOS 5 arc enabled port if metasyntactic protobuf

https://github.com/regwez/protobuf-objc-iOS5

Although I am having difficulties with the generated code (repeated type fields won't compile, at least for me), it might be a starting point for you.